# JSON TypeError - 'The "data" argument must be of type string'

Tags: php, json, autenticação-http

A API que eu estou tentando obter um token de acesso me dá as seguintes instruções *(ou você pode checar por aqui:https://developers.finove.com.br/authentication )*:

---

> Use o seu 'ClientId' e 'ClientSecret' pra buscar um token the acesso. A API segue os padrões de protocolo Oauth2.0

> A API aceita somente requisições em JSON, portanto todas devem incluir o cabeçalho 'Content-Type: application/json'.

**Os parâmetros vão no corpo da sua request**

*clientId* e *clientSecret* como string

**A resposta 200 ao seu POST conterá o token de acesso da seguinte forma:**

{

accessToken: "eyJhbGciOiJSUz..."

}

---

Até ai beleza. Então criei a seguinte função pra fazer um POST via JSON à API, pegar a resposta e obter o 'acessToken'.

```
<?php
// ignorar o $order, apenas uma função q eu pego e repasso pra outra
private function finove_auth($order){ 
        
    $authurl = 'https://api.finove.com.br/api/auth/authenticate';
    $client_id = $this->apiId;
    $client_secret = $this->apiSecret; 

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $authurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-Type: application/json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
            'clientId'      => $client_id,
            'clientSecret'  => $client_secret,
    ));

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

        if ( curl_errno( $ch ) ){
            echo 'Error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
            return $this->finove_payment_processing( $order );
        }
        else {
            curl_close($ch);

            $auth_string = json_decode($data, true);
            print_r($auth_string); // printa no console pra mim

            $this->finove_payment_processing( $order );
        }        
}
```

Mas algo não está funcionando, pois no console está me retornando duas coisas. A primeira é um

```
Fixed malformed JSON. Original:
```

E a segunda a resposta da API:

```
    array(7) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(9) "TypeError"
      ["message"]=>
      string(112) "The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined"
      ["errors"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["table"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["constraint"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["paramName"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["stack"]=>
      string(585) "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
        at Hmac.update (internal/crypto/hash.js:84:11)
        at ApiKeyService.verify (/usr/src/app/dist/api/services/ApiKeyService.js:15:18)
        at AuthController.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/dist/api/controllers/AuthController.js:17:48)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at fulfilled (/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:62)
        at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)"
    }
```

Não consigo descobrir o que fiz de errado, mas parece que o 'clientId e clienteSecret não estão sendo enviados corretamente..

Comment: Coloque seu array dentro de um json_encode

Comment: Postar resposta no campo de perguntas não é adequado, tem que ser no campo de respostas mesmo (ja repassei para o lugar certo). De qualquer forma, não é este tipo de pergunta que queremos no site. Nas próximas queira fornecer um [mcve] no lugar do problema original. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<sub>(repostado do corpo da pergunta, vide histórico)</sub>

---

Como os camaradas explicaram, eu não podia inserir uma array no POSTFIELDS e precisava encodar pro formato JSON. O Resultado final funcionando foi esse:

```
    
<?php
    
private function finove_auth(){
    
    
    
// Pega os dados de autenticação
    
    $clientId = $this->finoveID; 
    
    $clientSecret =  $this->finoveSecret;       
    
    $url = "https://api.finove.com.br/api/auth/authenticate";
    

    
// Formata os dados pro método JSON
    
    $data = array("clientId" => "$clientId", "clientSecret" => "$clientSecret");                                                                    
    
    $data_string = json_encode($data);   
    

    
    // Inicia o processo de request
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    

    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [ // propriedades do request
    
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string, //"{\n\"clientId\": \"$clientId\",\n\"clientSecret\": \"$clienteSecret\"\n}",
    
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    
        ],
    
    ]);
    
    
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl); // Executa o request
    
    $err = curl_error($curl); // Obtém o erro, caso ocorra algum
    
    
    
    curl_close($curl); // Fecha o request
    
    
    
    if ($err) {
    
        print_r("cURL Error #:" . $err); // printa o erro no log, caso ocorra
    
    } else {
    
        print_r($response); // printa a resposta da API no log para eu verificar se deu certo
    
    }
    
  
    
}
```